# Facebook login Api : unable to get email in php

Tags: php, facebook

Here, I am trying to get user email from `facebook login api.` By default i am getting id and name but unable to get email. Any help would be appreciated.

I have done with following. Please look in to this

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                    'appId'     => xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                    'secret'    =>  xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
                ));

$facebook->setAccessToken($facebook->getAccessToken());
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user){
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?locale=en_US&fields=first_name,last_name,email');
echo "<pre>"; print_r($user_profile); exit;
}

if(empty($user)){ 
    $loginurl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=> 'email, publish_actions, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_hometown, user_photos',
            'redirect_uri'  =>  $this->config->getConfig()->getBaseUrl().'social/index/facebooklogin',
            'display'=>'popup'
        ));
    $this->_redirect($loginurl);
}
```

**Output** :

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => xxxx
    [last_name] => xxxxxx
    [id] => xxxxxxxxx
)
```

I have gone through the some posts, posted on this portal. But not enough to solve my problem.

Thanks,

Comment: I think that your facebook app needs to get the read email permission before you can do that.

Comment: @Aurasphere i have already gave in `scope`.

Comment: What I meant is if when you created your FB app to get app secret and app id on Facebook, you did make sure that you gave email permission to your Facebook app, not through your PHP.

Comment: @Aurasphere : How to give email permission ? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Your app may be missing the `email` permission. It is usually automatically assigned but to set it manually, go to your app panel and do this:

[image]

In app review now you should see the email permission with a green light. Now you are good to go.

However, notice that you are not always able to get user's email. First of all, in order to get the email, the user has to be an email. Quote from [FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-email):

> Note, even if you request the email permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty.

Also, consider that in order to get an user email, that user has to authorize your app.

Comment: It is working for others `facebook accounts `. When i use mine it does not return email id :(

Comment: On Facebook, did you get the prompt that your app wants to read data from your profile?